# What is the reasoning behind char to int conversion output?

Tags: c

For example:

```
int x = 65535; char y = x; printf("%d\n", y)
```

This will output -1. Anyway to derive this by hand?

Comment: @MartinJames Not so sure, the `char` is automatically promoted to `int` for the varargs call, so it's fine I think.

Comment: @unwind oh - you may well be right.  So, it's the other set of a gazillion dupes, then:(

Comment: [No this will not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/613a0efca13207cd).

Comment: @MartinJames Then link to the "billion" dupes then, or are you on SO to troll?

Comment: @bedtime21: No MartinJames is not a troll, although the first comment made is not true.

Comment: @bedtime21 Can't be bothered to do that yet again.  You search.

Comment: @unwind: you're correct here, it's a common way of circumventing the printing of the encoded character rather than the number.

Comment: @bedtime21 oh, come on.  You deliberately used an incorrect format specifier, ie, bad code, and then asked SO users to explain why it's bad.  If it's implementation or undefined behaviour, it's still bad code!

Comment: @MartinJames It's not incorrect. The value is formally specified to be promoted to `int`, which is what `%d` requires.

Comment: @MartinJames Where? And others have already pointed it out to you that you're wrong. Please read my question.

Comment: I was wrong, sorry:)  The behaviour is not fomally undefined.  The code is merely bad as it's output depends upon the implementation of char as signed/unsigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to derive this by hand you need to know several implementation-defined aspects of your system - namely

- If `char` is signed or not
- If the `char` is signed, what representation scheme is used
- How does your system treat narrowing conversions of values that cannot be represented exactly in the narrow type.

Although the standard allows implementations to decide, a very common approach to narrowing conversions is to truncate the bits that do not fit in a narrow type. Assuming that this is the approach taken by your system, the first part of figuring out the output is to find the last eight bits of the `int` value being converted. In your case, 65535 is 1111111111111111<sub>2</sub>, so the last eight bits are all ones.

Now you need to decide the interpretation of 11111111<sub>2</sub>. On your system `char` is signed, and the system uses two's complement representation of negative values, so this pattern is interpreted as an eight-bit `-1` value.

When you call `printf`, eight-bit value of signed `char` is promoted to `int`, so the preserved value is printed.

On systems where `char` is unsigned by default the same pattern would be interpreted as 255.

Comment: I did not vote, but the conversion of `int` to `char` is not specified in the C standard in terms of bits. If the value can be represented in the new type, it is the result. Otherwise, the result is implementation-defined (including whther a trap occurs). So the answer should at least state that many implementations simply take the low bits and allow them to be reinterpreted in whatever format it uses for `char`. But an implementation could saturate, for example.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you very much for a thoughtful comment. I edited to mention your point about the narrowing conversion being implementation-defined.

Answer (score 4):

`65535` is `0xffff`

When converting to char, the left bits are left off:

`0xffff` AND `0xff` is `0xff`

When passing a char to a function, it is expanded to int. As the left-most bit of the char is a 1, this will be sign-extended, so it will become `0xffffffff` (32 bits)

This is `-1`, so -1 is printed as.

---

As Dasblinkenlight points out, it matters if the char is signed or unsigned (whether as a default in the implementation or as the declaration `unsigned char y`). My last lines would read for unsigned char:

When passing an unsgined char to a function, it is expanded to unsigned int. As it is unsigned, just zeroes are added at the left, so it will become `0x000000ff` (32 bits).

This is `255`, so 255 is printed as.

Comment: Arguments are promoted if the function does not have a prototype or they correspond to the `...` in the function declaration. Those apply in this situation, but not in general. Otherwise, an argument is converted to the type of its corresponding parameter.

Comment: When converting an `int` value to a `char` and the value is not representable, the result is implementation-defined. Many implementations just take the low bits as you state, but they may also trap, saturate, or define some other result.

Answer (score 0):

65535 when converted to `binary` is `1111111111111111`.
and when you assign this to a character variable it gets trimmed to least significant 8 bits which is `11111111`.

This is equivalent to -1 in `Binary`. `2's complement` of any number gives its `negative value`, hence 2's complement of 00000001:
11111110 + 1 = 11111111 is -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 65535;
```

The value of 'x' 65535 is equivalent to `0xffff (binary = 1111 1111 1111 1111)` in hexadecimal which represent the 2 Byte(16 bit) number .

Then the value of 'x' is converting into character 'y' and the size of character datatype is 1 Byte (8 bit) .so right side values of x is cutoff while assigning to 'y' because it only have 1B memory space .

So the value of 'y' is `0xff (binary = 1111 1111)` which is equal to `-1` in signed number integer representation .

And we are displaying the 'y' character value in term of integer by '%d' .